# Screeps: Can't import some modules using Typescript starter

Tags: typescript, screeps

I'm using the standard typescript starter and I'm having some issues getting modules to work when transmitted to screeps. For example,

```
import * as faker from 'faker';

export function creepNamer() {
  let randomName = faker.name.findName();
  return _.kebabCase(`${randomName}`);
}
```

Gives me an error that `name` does not exist on faker. When I check `faker`, I find `undefined`.

Does anyone know why some modules are inexplicably inoperable/export nothing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you post your folder structure of your project so that I can dive into your problem?
2. tried to import it like this? "./folder/script"
3. module resolution correct?
4. Have you checked your tsconfig.json for correct in/-exclude ?
5. Some stuff won't work with screeps. Example: 'http' from node.

example tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "dist",
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Yeah I wait for your answer. Then I can try to help you better.
Greets~